# How to make a call from one Google Apps Script to a function in another?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there an easy way of making a call from one Google Apps script to a function in another?

I'm writing two scripts, one which should use functions from the other. I want the two to have different sharing permissions, however, so I don't want to put them in the same project.

I can't seem to find any "require Xxx.gs" type function in the documentation.

I found this:
[Call functions from another "class" / file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335646/call-functions-from-another-class-file)

But I get "xxx function not found" errors if I try to call a function from a different file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Corey mentioned in the post you refer to you need to use [libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries?hl=en) to do what you want.
You can not use functions from another project in a project (but you can of course use any function from different script files **inside a project**)

Answer (score 1):

Besides libraries, if you actually want to keep the projects separate you can publish a service url and use parameters to call it from the other script with urlFetch, as in myserviceurl?call=myfunction&param1=x