# What is the easiest way to clean up and publish a useful Google sheet/script I've written?

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I have written a [Google Sheet with script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17-UuMBeqfIZQ9Qf-w-VzCuENI9TTkLt3lP7-z6xQ1Ac/edit#gid=719802045) to pull economic time-series data from FRED, Federal Reserve Economic Data maintained by the Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis, into Google Sheets. I would like to share the sheet/script freely/openly and widely. I am an amateur coder, and while the script is fully functional, I am not sure if the coding is up to rigorous specs, if it's safe enough, etc. How can I get help with polishing and sharing this project?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest organizing your code by moving each relevant function to its own .gs file following this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335646/call-functions-from-another-class-filehttps://).

Also for reference on how to manage and deploy your App Script project you can read more about it here on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments)